# Pass multiple strings to verify CAfile in OpenSSL

Tags: node.js, openssl, verify

With cat its possible to use `cat <(echo "example") <(echo "example")`.
I'd like to use this method also in OpenSSL:

```
openssl verify -CAfile <(echo "PEM") <(echo "PEM")
```

but i have this error: `Error loading file /dev/fd/63`

How can i solve this?

Info:
At the end id like to execute this command in node.js and pass in the two PEM args (as string).

Answer (score 0):

1. You do not specify the CA file: it should be `openssl verify -CAfile /path/to/cafile`
2. You do not provide the contents of the PEM file. It should be something like `echo -e "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n...-----END CERTIFICATE-----"`, where the `...` is the certificate encoded in Base64, or much easier: `cat /path/to/pemfile1 /path/to/pemfile2 | openssl verify -CAfile /path/to/cafile`

Comment: I didn't ask my question precisely enough sorry.
Exactly this is my goal not to use a file on the disk but a string(using echo "example").
Here we can see an example how we can use process substitution to imitate a file but its not a file just to output of another command->
https://github.com/pkrumins/bash-redirections-cheat-sheet/blob/master/bash-redirections-cheat-sheet.txt
And here->
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17107/process-substitution-and-pipe
This already works a little bit better but still not desired behaviou
openssl verify -CAfile < <(echo "....") < <(echo "....")

Comment: What do you want to provide over stdin? The two certs or the CA file, or all of them?

Comment: I try to have my own PKI. So i have a root cert and an intermediate cert which signs requests for entites. Now i want to check an entities cert. For this i use verify. And verify -CAfile to pass the two certs(root&intermediate) plus the entity cert: cat root.pem intermediate.pem > ca-chain.pem then openssl verify -CAfile ca-chain.pem entity.pem